# Refresh page with Jquery Connected Sortable if item is dropped into certain container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

My connected sortables work great but I'm trying to make one improvement:

If a user drags in item into the "#buttonmaker" sortable, I want the entire page to refresh.

What's happening is if a user drags an item into the buttonmaker sortable, my ajax sorting.php page updates the database with a new menu button based off the item the user dropped in. After that, the page needs to be refreshed so the user can see the new menu button that they just created.

95% of the time though users will not be using the `#buttonmaker` and I don't need a page refresh... ajax does it's thing. It's just for this one `#buttonmaker` container that I need a page refresh. Thanks for any help.

```
$(function() {
    $("#draft, #trash, #a_bunch_more_divs, #buttonmaker").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
        opacity: 0.6,
        scroll: true,
        update : function () 
        { 
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "sorting.php",
                data: 
                {
                    draft_sort:$("#draft").sortable('serialize'),
                    trash_sort:$("#trash").sortable('serialize'),
                    other_sort:$("#a_bunch_more_divs").sortable('serialize'),
                    buttonmaker_sort:$("#buttonmaker").sortable('serialize')
                }
            });
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Updated Code (I've changed a few cosmetic things since the original post):

```
$(function() {
    var refreshNeeded = false;
    $("#draft, #published, #trash").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
        opacity: 0.6,
        scroll: true,
        update : function (event, ui) 
        { 
            var $sortable = $(this);
            if(ui.item.parent()[0] != this) return;
            var postData = {};
            postData[$sortable.attr('id') + '_sort'] = $sortable.sortable('serialize');
            if(ui.sender){
                postData[$sortable.attr('id') + '_sort'] = ui.sender.sortable('serialize');
            }
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "js/post_sorting.php",
                data: postData,
                success: function() {
                    if(($sortable.attr('id') == "published")) refreshNeeded = true;
                    /*window.location.reload(true);*/
                }
            });
        }
    }).disableSelection();
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        if(refreshNeeded){
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I had been trying over and over to do the `window.loaction.reload` inside the sortable function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a good idea to check for the outcome of your ajax call. Also, sending the whole thing on every update is a waste of resources, as the update event gets called for both the source and the target sortable.

As for the refresh, you just need to set a boolean variable whenever you think a refresh is needed, then bind an event to `.ajaxStop()` to run when all ajax requests have completed.

```
$(function(){
    var refreshNeeded = false;

    $("#draft, #trash, #a_bunch_more_divs, #buttonmaker").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
        opacity: 0.6,
        scroll: true,
        update : function(event, ui){
            var $sortable = $(this);

            // To avoid double-firing the event, return if it's not the sortable
            // where the item was dropped into.
            if(ui.item.parent()[0] != this) return;

            // Create object from the current sortable to post
            var postData = {};
            postData[$sortable.attr('id') + '_sort'] = $sortable.sortable('serialize');

            // If the item came from a connected sortable, include that in the post too
            if(ui.sender){
                postData[ui.sender.attr('id') + '_sort'] = ui.sender.sortable('serialize');
            }

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "sorting.php",
                data: postData,
                success: function(){
                    // What if we're all happy?

                    // If the triggering sortable was the buttonmaker, set the refresh flag
                    if($sortable.attr('id') == "buttonmaker")) RefreshNeeded = true;
                },
                error: function(){
                    // What if there is an error?
                }
            });
        }
    }).disableSelection();

    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        // All requests have completed, check if we need to refresh
        if(refreshNeeded){
            // Refresh the page (just a simple reload for now)
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:** Added bit of code to only send current sortable in the post data. It assumes that the name of the data will always be `id_sort`, where `id` is the id of your sortable.

**Edit 2:** Added some more bits to avoid double-firing the event, so it will only submit once per move. If item came from a connected sortable, it will include both sortables in the request.

Comment: Thanks. There is a lot of nice tidbits of code in this example. I noticed what you are saying about the sort being sent twice each time. Wasn't sure what to do there.

Comment: Added something of an idea to post only the current sortable that the event is called for, although you need some error handling in case a post fails. For example if you're dragging an element from one sortable to the other and the second ajax call fails.

Comment: Added bits to avoid double-firing the event and only submit once per move, less error-prone on the backend. Note that it's all untested code.

Comment: The "fire-once" is working great. That cuts down half the overhead. I'm not really worried about this, but it still looks like all item id's are being passed. IE: if I move an item from #draft to #trash, firebug still shows the #published info being passed. Should that not happen?

Comment: Did you change the ajax call's `data` property to use the new object? `data: postData,` As I said it's all untested, if you find any typos or errors, let me know.

Comment: Nope, I missed the data change change. I changed it and now it's a little funky. If I have a,b,c in #draft and I move "a" into #trash, then "b" and "c" get moved to #trash and "a" stays in #draft.

Comment: Hmm... I copied the code to jsfiddle, I only removed the ajax bits and put in an alert to show what would be posted: http://jsfiddle.net/QWzpJ/ It seems to work ok. Are you getting that error on a refresh? If so, are you sure you're processing the data on the backend correctly?

Comment: Yeah, it might be. I'll have to check it when I have time. I'll just go with what I've got for now since it does everything I need. Thanks for all your help.